# kafka consumer turn on off runtime, process messages in series

Tags: spring-kafka

My kafka listener  should process  messages in sequential order , onMessage  method should process  messages synchronously,  I dont want my listener to process multiple messages at the same  time, the onmessage method  first stops

> org.springframework.kafka.listener.MessageListenerContainer

then delgates payload to a synchronized method, after complete processing , starts listener back. Other options ofcousrse are to use a  blocking queue, executor service etc,  need advice on  better strategy to achieve this, does kafka consumer has any feature built to process messages in series? 
here is my code.

I changed implementation  to this

```
    public static class KafkaReadMsgTask implements  Runnable{

    @Override
    public void run() {
        KakfaMsgConumerImpl  kakfaMsgConumerImpl=null;;
        try{
            kakfaMsgConumerImpl=SpContext.getBean(KakfaMsgConumerImpl.class);
            kakfaMsgConumerImpl.pollFormDef();
            kakfaMsgConumerImpl.pollFormData();
      } catch (Exception e){
          logger.error(" kafka listener  errors "+e);
          kakfaMsgConumerImpl.pauseTask();
       }  
    }
}


    @Component
public static class KakfaMsgConumerImpl {

    @Autowired
    ObjectMapper  mapper;

    @Autowired
    FormSink  formSink;

    @Autowired
    Environment  env;

    @Resource(name="formDefConsumer")
    Consumer formDefConsumer;

    @Resource(name="formDataConsumer")
    Consumer formDataConsumer;

    ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();

    public void startPolling() throws Exception{
        executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(new KafkaReadMsgTask(),10, 3,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }
    public void pauseTask(){
        try{
            Thread.sleep (120000l);
        }catch(Exception e){
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
    public void  pollFormDef() throws Exception{
        ConsumerRecords<Long, String> records =formDefConsumer.poll(0);
        if(!records.isEmpty()){
            int recordsCount=records.count();
            if(logger.isDebugEnabled()){
                logger.debug(" form-def consumer poll records size "+recordsCount);
            }
            if(records.count()>1){
                logger.warn(" form-def consumer poll returned records more than 1 , expected 1 , received "+recordsCount);
            }
            ConsumerRecord<Long,String> record= records.iterator().next();
            processFormDef(record.key(), record.value());
        }
    }
    void pollFormData() throws Exception{
        ConsumerRecords<Long, String> records =formDataConsumer.poll(0);
        if(!records.isEmpty()){
            int recordsCount=records.count();
            if(logger.isDebugEnabled()){
                logger.debug(" form-data consumer poll records size "+recordsCount);
            }
            if(records.count()>1){
                logger.warn(" form-data consumer poll returned records more than 1 , expected 1 , received "+recordsCount);
            }               ConsumerRecord<Long,String> record= records.iterator().next();
            processFormData(record.key(), record.value());
        }
    }
    void processFormDef(Long key, String msg) throws  Exception{
        if(logger.isDebugEnabled()){
            logger.debug(" key "+key+" payload : "+msg);
        }
        FormDefinition  formDefinition= mapper.readValue(msg, FormDefinition.class);
        formSink.createFromDef(formDefinition);
        logger.debug(" processed  message,  key: "+key+ " msg : "+msg);
        Thread.sleep(60000l);
    }

    void processFormData(Long key, String msg) throws  Exception{
        if(logger.isDebugEnabled()){
            logger.debug(" key "+key+" payload : "+msg);
        }
        FormData  formData= mapper.readValue(msg, FormData.class);
        formSink.persists(formData);
        logger.debug(" processed  message,  key: "+key+ " msg : "+msg);
        Thread.sleep(60000l);
    }



}
```

Comment: You can configure your consumer to poll message one by one by setting this property: `max.poll.records` to 1. It's the maximum number of records returned in a single call to poll.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a message-driven listener container is not the right technology for this application; it looks like you want to consume messages alternately from two different topics.

Furthermore, stopping the container on the consumer thread won't take effect anyway, until the thread exits the method, at which time the consumer will be closed.

I would suggest you use the consumer factory to create two consumers; subscribe to the topics, set the `max.poll.records` on each to 1 and call the `poll()` method on each alternately.